Instabug reports aren't submitted for Flutter app, only on Android
When I report a bug or a crash happens on Android, I won't receive it on Instabug dashboard. While it works on iOS.
I tried to use show method & then reported a bug, but don't receive it on Instabug website.
Even after sending a suggestion or reporting a bug, I can see the dialog about successful action with a message "We've received your feedback!"
Instabug integration code
await Instabug.init(
      token: currentConfig.instabug.apiToken,
      invocationEvents: [
        InvocationEvent.shake,
        InvocationEvent.screenshot,
      ],
    );
    await Instabug.setWelcomeMessageMode(
      WelcomeMessageMode.disabled,
    );

Versions
instabug_flutter: ^13.3.0
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.1)
compileSdkVersion 34
minSdkVersion 28
Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)

Device Model
All Android devices.
Logs After calling show method:
W/System  (14952): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(14952): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
D/FirebaseAuth(14952): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 5Nc5RmftLCQasBfpFtcjCCvrAg03 ).
[log]       'event tracked - EventName.ProfileScreen - true',
        name: 'TrackingRepositoryImpl',
        
W/ActivityThread(14952): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ee2b03e
E/ResourcesCompat(14952): Failed to find font-family tag
I/chatty  (14952): uid=10150(com...dev) identical 6 lines
E/ResourcesCompat(14952): Failed to find font-family tag
E/ResourcesCompat(14952): Failed to find font-family tag
I/chatty  (14952): uid=10150(com....dev) identical 2 lines
E/ResourcesCompat(14952): Failed to find font-family tag
E/ResourcesCompat(14952): Failed to find font-family tag
I/chatty  (14952): uid=10150(com....dev) identical 2 lines
E/ResourcesCompat(14952): Failed to find font-family tag
E/ResourcesCompat(14952): Failed to find font-family tag
I/chatty  (14952): uid=10150(com....dev) identical 2 lines
E/ResourcesCompat(14952): Failed to find font-family tag
D/EGL_emulation(14952): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7365a2f6e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7365a00940)

After pressing send button to report a bug:
W/RecyclerView(14952): No adapter attached; skipping layout
W/ActivityThread(14952): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@219ae09
E/ResourcesCompat(14952): Failed to find font-family tag
I/chatty  (14952): uid=10150(com....dev) identical 4 lines
E/ResourcesCompat(14952): Failed to find font-family tag
D/EGL_emulation(14952): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7365a2f6e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7365a00940)
D/EGL_emulation(14952): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7365a2f6e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7365a00940)
D/EGL_emulation(14952): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7365a2f6e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7365a00940)
D/EGL_emulation(14952): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7365a2f6e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7365a00940)
I/lorermobile.de(14952): Background concurrent copying GC freed 32934(2020KB) AllocSpace objects, 39(2068KB) LOS objects, 43% free, 7929KB/13MB, paused 14us total 118.943ms
E/IBG-Core(14952): Error in Single Thread Executor(IBG-network-single-executor-0). cause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/perf/network/FirebasePerfUrlConnection;
W/ActivityThread(14952): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@e537b91
D/EGL_emulation(14952): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7361366c00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x730f935c80)
D/EGL_emulation(14952): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7361366c00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x730f935c80)
D/EGL_emulation(14952): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7365a2f6e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7365a00940)
D/AutofillManager(14952): onActivityFinishing(): calling cancelLocked()


I think firebase-perf plugin has conflict with instabug since if I remove id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf' from app/build.gradle, then I can receive crashes on Instabug website.
